# RE: Automating a Calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, calculator

I'm just wondering how I'd go about automating this:

5.00 + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00% + 4.00%

4% (4.00%) is there 80 times.

But, see, I need it to be like: 5.00 + 4.00% = 5.20 (new base number to work off) + 4.00% = 5.408 (new base number to work off) and so on

I need it to be done 80 times...

Comment: Home work question? Have you tried searching for "Compound Interest"?

Comment: Not home work. Yes, I know what compound interesting is. This actually has zero relation to money. Sorry!

Comment: Well it's the same idea.

Comment: `5+4%` is a loose expression of the mathematical formula `5*1.04`. From that the answer should be obvious...

Comment: It's basically nearly 150. Yes?

Comment: Nope, the answer is 115.25 `=5*(1.04)^80`

Answer (score 1):

This is where something call exponents comes in handy. 5*2*2*2 = 5*2^3 - we have 3 2's, so we do 2^3.

Now, +4% is the same as *1.04. You're repeating that 80 times. So, it'd be the same as 1.04^80.

Given that you're putting it in a %, I'd think you're doing stuff with money. The Future Value = The Present Value * (1+ Rate)^How many times.

Which becomes FV=5*(1+.04)^80

If you haven't hit high school yet (or the later years of middle, depending), kudos for going out and trying to figure stuff out on your own. If you have, there's a reason they said to pay attention in math.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple, You just use the Iterations option,, for the formula particularly, for this Go to the File menu, then Options, then find Calculation, there you find check box by default its 1. Set it to 40 and reset to default after finish your job.